# yii2 index.php rewrite not working

Tags: php, yii2

I recloned a yii2 project after reinstalling my system.The project was ok before but now prettyurl is not working.(index.php needed in url). I have set the htaccess and added url manager rule in config. What can be the problem .Please help!

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: http://tutsnare.com/remove-index-php-from-url-in-yii2/

Comment: Have you made 'enablePrettyUrl' => true?